# Python subprocess.call can't open Notepad.exe?

Tags: python, subprocess

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe'])
```

Leads to error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing
>   IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 3, in 
>       pass   File "c:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 172, in call
>       return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()   File "c:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 408, in **init**
>       errread, errwrite)   File "c:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 663, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo) WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

But I can run Notepad using that exact path from the filename bar of a folder window.  What am I missing?

Comment: That string contains a newline character in the middle!  Specify it as a raw string: `r'C:\...'` so that backslashes aren't given any special meaning.

Comment: Just use 'notepad' as cmd and 'shell=True'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the unescaped backlashes in your path. Python interprets `'\n'` as a single newline character.

Either escape the backslashes:

```py
'C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe'
```

Or (preferred) use a *raw string* with an `r` prefix:

```py
r'C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that might work for you 
`subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe'])`